# Can't figure out WSO2-ESB Deployment Synchronizer

Tags: wso2

I can't figure out idea about svn DepSync: we have default repository inside `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/deployment/server`. Ok. If I want to use this default repo, then I shouldn`t make my own svn repo? So In this case I leave

```
<DeploymentSynchronizer><Enabled>false</Enabled>
```

inside carbon.xml? Or I should set up `<Enabled>true</Enabled>` and also set `<SvnUrl>` to `<SvnUrl><PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/deployment/server</SvnUrl>`?
In other case, If I want to set up my own repository, I should disable default repo `<PRODUCT_HOME>/repository/deployment/server`? So, in this case I should change parameter `<RepositoryLocation>${carbon.home}/repository/deployment/server/</RepositoryLocation>` to something `<RepositoryLocation>url_of_my_own_repo/</RepositoryLocation>` inside carbon.xml? Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Deployment synchronization is used to synchronize artifacts deployed across nodes in a product cluster. When you enable depsync and provide a svn repository location, the artifacts gets committed to that location. The other nodes should be configured to the same svn repository for depsync. This way the they will sync with the first nodes' artifacts and maintain consistency.

In a non-cluster environment, depsync is not needed.